# Broadcast not being received Android

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I am making an IntentService from my Activity to do some background work, and from that service, I am broadcasting an intent to receive some data, but the broadcast isn't being received.

Here are my classes:

> TwitterService.java

```
 public class TwitterService extends IntentService {

    public TwitterService() {
        super("TwitterService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
        Bundle bundle = workIntent.getExtras();

        List<twitter4j.Status> tweets = new ArrayList<twitter4j.Status>();

        Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();

        try{
            tweets = twitter.search(new Query(bundle.getString("query").toString())).getTweets();
            Query query = new Query(bundle.getString("query").toString());
            query.resultType(Query.ResultType.recent);
            tweets = twitter.search(query).getTweets();

            System.out.println("results fetched");

            Intent test = new Intent();
            test.putExtra("a", "a");
            sendBroadcast(test);
        }
        catch (TwitterException e){
            System.out.println("Twitter Exception!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And

> TwitterReceiver.java

```
    public class TwitterReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        Log.d("Twitter Receiver", b.getString("a").toString());
    }
}
```

And

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="com.example.dhuzz.first" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".MainApp"
        android:debuggable="true" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".TwitterService"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <receiver android:name=".TwitterReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="TwitterBroadcast"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: While you want broadcast reciever?

Comment: I'm a newbie in Android, I need to send data from Service back to the Activity. I read online, Android docs say use Broadcasts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code of Broadcast intent like this

```
        Intent test = new Intent("TwitterBroadcast");
        test.putExtra("a", "a");
        sendBroadcast(test);
```